# USB Stick became Read-Only after using Pen Drive USB Installer

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, usb-drive, read-only

Yesterday I tried to make my 16Gb USB Stick bootable with Ubuntu 13.04 (Desktop x64). After some time because nothing changed I canceled the progress and decided to burn a DVD. The installation with the DVD worked well but now my USB Stick is set to readonly and I can't get it fixed. It has NO physical switch for setting it readonly.

**Please help me :]** (And I'm sorry if my english isn't as well)

Answer (score -1):

Try to create a USB STICK use Flash disk size 4 or 8 gigabytes

Comment: I have already installed Ubuntu perfectly using the DVD but now I can't use/format my USB Stick anymore.